# WPF specify row in grid of programmatically created datagrid

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm trying to find out how can I set up `row` and `columnspan` of programmatically created `DataGrid`. My code adds it in the first row:

```
private DataGrid CreateTextBoxesDataGrid(string name)
{
    DataGrid dataGrid = new DataGrid();
    dataGrid.Name = name;
    //row ???
    dataGrid.Style = Resources["AppSettingsDataGridStyle"] as Style;
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(CreateNameColumn());
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(CreateTextValueColumn());
    dataGrid.Columns.Add(CreateComentColumn());
    return dataGrid;
}

...
mainGrid.Children.Add(CreateTextBoxesDataGrid("eeej"));
```

Comment: What do you mean by `columnspan`? Setting it for the DataGrid itself? DataGridRow does not define a ColumnSpan attached property. I would suggest just binding to a source list of objects and manipulating that.

Comment: I'm trying to write something which would generate this: ``<DataGrid x:Name="eeej" Grid.ColumnSpan="6" Grid.Row="7" Style="{StaticResource AppSettingsDataGridStyle}" >``

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To set a ColumnSpan on the DataGrid itself does not really make sense. The ColumnSpan defines how many columns a control on the grid will span across. So as you see, this is something you want to set per control that is INSIDE the grid, not on the grid itself.

Are you intending to set the width of the column of the DataGrid? If that is the case, you can do something like this:

```
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Auto);
```

Or like this if you want it based on the entire width of the DataGrid:

```
column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
```

If you want to add a new row programatically to the DataGrid, you can do this:

```
public class DataGridRow
{
    public string Col1 { get; set; }
    public string Col2 { get; set; }
}
```

...

```
var row = new DataGridRow{ Col1 = "Column1", Col2 = "Column2" };
dataGrid.Items.Add(row);
```

If you want to set how many columns the DataGrid will span inside it's parent grid, you can use the following:

```
   Grid.SetColumnSpan(dataGrid, columnsToSpan);
```

I'm just guessing what you want here, if I did not understand you correctly, feel free to reply to my answer with more details.

Comment: Based on answers to my question I'm guessing I'm doing something very bad. I have one ``Grid`` named ``mainGrid``, which has set several rows and columns. I use ``dataGrid`` to display data from xml file. Now I want to generate another ``dataGrid`` to display another bunch of data. My problem is that I do not know how can I set ``Grid.row`` and ``Grid.columnspan`` when generating ``dataGrid`` as posted in question.

Comment: In order to set how many columns the DataGrid will span in its parent grid, you use the static function on the grid like the last code in my comment (Grid.SetColumnSpan)

Answer (score 1):

That's the code:

```
   Grid.SetColumnSpan(dataGrid, colSpan);
   Grid.SetRow(dataGrid, row);
```